# How is the GridsearchCV Score calculated?

Tags: python, cross-validation, python-3.x, gridsearchcv

How is the score of GridsearchCV calculated? Is the score a percentage? Does this mean higher is a better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The score is based on the scorer defined in the scoring argument. Meaning, the scorer can be any of the default metrics, such as precision, accuracy or F1-score
(e.g., [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)); or a custom scorer.
For a scorer (by convention), higher value is better.
The value is not necessarily a percentage, but is often normalized between 0 and 1.

Comment: I create a Gradient Boost Regressor with a GridSearchcv but dont define the score. Whta does the score mean by default?

Comment: If None, the estimator’s score method is used. This means in your case the Gradient Boost Regressor default scorer is used (that is coefficient R^2)

Comment: and r² is not a percentage?

Comment: By convention, we use word `score` when higher is better. We use word `loss` when less is better. When you don't have any particular in mind, use `metric`.

Comment: @ml_learner r2 is not percentage (and it's not r-squared). It's 'kinda' normalized, but you can use it to compare models just fine.

1.0 - is perfect model
0.0 - this is constant answer model
<0.0 - model goes wrong

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica I didn't know about the score / loss convention, but seems logic. Changed the answer accordingly.